# How many "reps" of each exercise do you do?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, vocabulary

What does "reps" mean in this sentence?

> "How many **reps** of each exercise do you do?"

Comment: Welcome, Fellix. I had a look in a dictionary and found the answer you are seeking. [reps](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rep#h46976653499680). Please be sure to check a dictionary first, before asking here.

Comment: A useful search tip: if _your_ dictionary doesn't happen to list a particular short word, look around to see if it might make sense as an abbreviation of a longer word. Conveniently, dictionaries tend to list words in alphabetical order, so e.g. all the words that begin with "rep" will be grouped together. (Or you could just check another dictionary; there are plenty of them online nowadays.)

Answer (score 11):

It refers to "repetition".

> A repetition can be defined as one complete movement of a particular exercise. Repetitions are simply a means to count the number of exercise movements performed in a given amount of time

[Source](https://www.sharecare.com/health/types-of-exercise-programs/what-is-a-repetition)